# Trying to load view controller as uiview to subview of mainvc

Tags: iphone

One main vc and other vcs and definition of other vcs in main vc. These other vcs have uiviews  in their class . Now how can i add these other vcs as subviews to main vc

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[self.view addSubview:baseView];
// Displays UIImageView
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                     initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ka1_046.png"]];
myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[baseView addSubview:myImage]; 
// create the UIToolbar at the bottom of the view controller
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 40)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[baseView addSubview:toolbar];

//Add Play Button
self.playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.playButton];

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[audioPlayer pause];
[self pauseTimer];
[self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}else{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[audioPlayer play];
[self resumeTimer];
[self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
 if(isFirstTime == YES)
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                        target:self
                                        selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:NO];
    isFirstTime  = NO;
}} }


- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender{  
 First *first = [[First alloc] init];
 first.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
 CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
 [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
 [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
 [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
 [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
 [baseView addSubview:first.view];
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
 [first release];
```

If in displayviewaction i do

```
[baseView addSubview:first.view];
```

so that as per playpauseAction it replaces UIImageView with first.view after 11 seconds as subview. It gives message that use of undeclared identifier baseView.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

UIView *baseView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *baseView;
```

// .m

```
@synthesize baseView;
```

make this part:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[self.view addSubview:baseView];
```

to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
self.baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[self.view addSubview:self.baseView];
```

**AND**

make this:

```
[baseView addSubview:first.view];
```

to this:

```
[self.baseView addSubview:first.view];
```

or you can still use the above.

then you're done. :)

Comment: Now it is replacing UIImageview with first.view but after replacing with first.view it should still show the uitoolbar below always of UIImageview no matter which view controller i m loading as subview of uiimageview.

Comment: I think you have to manually put it in the nib or put the toolbar in either of viewDidAppear,viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: In viewDidLoad of mainvc already has [self.baseView addSubview:toolbar];

Comment: Your adding of subviews seem to be mixed up. Can u explain clearly the views hierarchy. Or how it should be presented?

Comment: Mainvc has uitoolbar without navigationcontroller and tabbarcontroller. when play button is pressed on the uitoolbar it will execute playpauseaction which further executes displayviewsaction and start loading view controllers view one after the other based on different time intervals

Comment: currently i m adding manually [self.view addSubview:toolbar]; toolbar like this in each view controller's view but instead of adding manually toolbar should show itself from uimageview as i m adding all these view controller views as subview of uiimageview

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring baseView inside -(void) viewDidLoad. It's scope is limited within that method. Declare it as iVar.

```
@interface YourMainViewController : UIViewController
{
  UIView* baseView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIView* baseView;
```

You know the drill.